# How to get screen position of certain component

Tags: screen, c++builder

### Issue

Well, I have designed a dialog form that is called when user select certain cells (single selection, not multiple selection) on a TStringGrid component.

This dialog form would be centered on the center of one of those selected cell.

BUT it does not happens :(

### Possible solution = what I would like to have

I would like to get screen position of a cell, i.e. absolute screen coordinates, instead of those obtained by `CellRect()`.

### What I'm doing

To calculate the center of the cell, I currently have to sum coordinates of following components on that way:

```
TRect pos;

pos = table->CellRect(Col,Row);

pos.Left += form->Left + panel->Left + frame->Left + table->Left;
pos.Right += pos->Left;

pos.Top += form->Top + panel->Top + frame->Top + table->Top;
pos.Bottom += pos->Top;
```

Then centering the dialog:

```
dialog->Left = (pos->Left + pos->Right)/2 - dialog->Width/2;
dialog->Top = (pos->Top + pos->Bottom)/2 - dialog->Height/2;
```

Because some unknown reason, Col and Row adds a offset to the correct position of the dialog, so great Col and Row values set dialog position to great distances of correct position (the center of selected cell).

```
 ___screen________________________________________
|                                                 |
|   ___form___________________________________    |
|  |                                          |   |
|  |                                          |   |
|  |   ___panel____________________________   |   |
|  |  |                                    |  |   |
|  |  |   ___frame_______________          |  |   |
|  |  |  |                       |         |  |   |
|  |  |  |                       |         |  |   |
|  |  |  |  ___table_________    |         |  |   |
|  |  |  | |                 |   |         |  |   |
|  |  |  | |       _cell_    |   |         |  |   |
|  |  |  | |      |______|   |   |         |  |   |
|  |  |  | |                 |   |         |  |   |
|  |  |  | |_________________|   |         |  |   |
|  |  |  |_______________________|         |  |   |
|  |  |____________________________________|  |   |
|  |                                          |   |
|  |                                          |   |
|  |__________________________________________|   |
|_________________________________________________|
```

### And if I have the screen position of the table or of the selected cell

It will become so easy to implement and to detect those offset errors, because there will be less components coordinates on the sum above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `CellRect()` to get the **client coordinates** and then convert them to **screen coordinates**.  There are several ways to do that:

1. use the `TControl::ClientToScreen()` method:

   ```
   TRect pos = table->CellRect(Col, Row);

   TPoint &tl = pos.TopLeft();
   tl = table->ClientToScreen(tl);

   TPoint &br = pos.BottomRight();
   br = table->ClientToScreen(br);
   ```
2. offset the `TRect` using the `TControl::ClientOrigin` property, which specifies the **screen coordinates** of the top-left corner of the StringGrid's client area:

   ```
   TPoint pt = table->ClientOrigin;
   TRect pos = table->CellRect(Col, Row);
   ::OffsetRect(&pos, pt.x, pt.y);
   ```
3. use the Win32 API `MapWindowPoints()` function (keep in mind that `TStringGrid` is a graphical control, so it does not have its own window, you have to use its Parent window instead), eg:

   ```
   TRect pos = table->CellRect(Col, Row);
   ::OffsetRect(&pos, table->Left, table->Top);
   ::MapWindowPoints(table->Parent->Handle, NULL, (LPPOINT)&pos, 2);
   ```